# --target option of docker build command doesn't work in aws codeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-codebuild

I use a multi stages docker build for my aws codeBuild to build my application.
The shape of my docker file is :

```
FROM strapi/base:14-alpine AS dependencies
...

FROM strapi/base:14-alpine As liveProduction
ENV NODE_ENV="production"
COPY --from=dependencies /toto /toto
....

FROM strapi/base:14-alpine As liveDevelopment
ENV NODE_ENV="development"
COPY --from=dependencies /toto /toto
...
```

And to build my application for production, i use aws buildspect.yml and in this file i have the following comande :

```sh
docker build --no-cache --target liveProduction -t app-facej-backoffice .
```

This command doesn't work very well, because, all stages are executed with the following order : dependencies, liveProduction, liveDevelopment. In this case, i want only dependencies and liveDevelopment to be executed.

I would like to know what is the problem ? Why the --target option of docker build doesn't work in codeBuild?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, i want liveProduction to be build. That's why i put in the command line --target liveProduction.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @SouleymaneNdiaye unless a formatting error, are the `AS` arguments written properly? I.e., you have only `AS` (in all-caps) in the first stage and the two subsequent stages have `As`.

Comment: Try this: `docker build --no-cache --target liveProduction --tag app-facej-backoffice .`

Answer (score 3):

Skipping build stages is a feature of buildkit that creates a dependency graph. This is the default in newer versions of docker, so either the release of docker doesn't have buildkit, or you need an environment variable (`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`) set to enable it:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --no-cache --target liveProduction -t app-facej-backoffice .
```

Comment: This is the right answer! Thanks @BMitch